# Jest matcher to match any one of three values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have this selector in my component whose default state is `'' (empty)` string but when `change` event is fired user can select any one of the three values that is 6, 12 or 24

```
it("feedform testing the selector feed frequency for value of 6, 12, 24 ", () => {
  const addFeedForm = shallow(
    <FeedForm
      submitForm={() => {}}
      setFeedData={() => {}}
      formType="add"
      feedsubmit={{
        status: null,
        error: {
          formsubmitwarning: "",
          feedname: "",
          feedurl: "",
          feedposttype: "",
          feedfrequency: "",
          feedpost: "",
          feedhashtag: "",
          formloginid: ""
        }
      }}
    />
  );
  expect(addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency).toEqual("");
  addFeedForm.simulate("change");
  expect(addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency).toEqual(6 || 12 || 24);
});
```

Now while writing unit test cases for this I quickly went through Jest documentation to find matcher for any one of the three value but found no matcher that does that.

I even tried using `|| (or)` operator in `toEqual` and `toBe` matcher but as you guessed it didn't work. Is there a way to make it work or should I skip the test all together?

**Note: I am using Enzyme with Jest**

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In order to one among the expected value, you can reverse the comparison and test it using [`toContain`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem) method like

```
expect(addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency).toEqual('');
addFeedForm.simulate('change');
expect([6, 12, 24]).toContain(addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency)
```

Comment: toContainEqual?

Answer (score 23):

The [`jest-extended`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended) library provides a [`.toBeOneOf([members])`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended/blob/v0.11.0/README.md#tobeoneofmembers) matcher:

```js
it("feedform testing the selector feed frequency for value of 6, 12, 24 ", () => {
  expect(addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency).toBeOneOf([6, 12, 24]);
});
```

Answer (score 17):

There is no method on the Jest API to match multiple values.

A way to do this check is using a regex:

```
expect(String(addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency)).toMatch(/^6|12|24$/);
```

Answer (score 13):

Another way to achieve this is to do the comparison outside of Jest's assertion and simply expect that to be true:

```
expect(
    addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency === 6 ||
    addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency === 12 ||
    addFeedForm.state().feedfrequency === 24
).toBe(true)
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is assertions without actual data that caused the problem, whilst [`toContain`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem) would highlight such data.

Comment: To expand on the above: `expect(value).toBe(true)` should never be used unless you're actually testing something that returns a boolean, because the [diagnostics](http://growing-object-oriented-software.com/figures/feedback-on-diagnostics.svg) of "expected false to be true" are pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a regex of allowed values from an object

Here's an example using object matching:

```js
const userStatusValues = Object.values(statusObject).join('|')
const possibleUserStatusRegex = new RegExp(`^${userStatusValues}$`)

const exampleResponse = {
      id: expect.any(Number),
      status: expect.stringMatching(possibleUserStatusRegex),
      email: 'myemail@email.com',
}

expect(result).toMatchObject(exampleResponse)
```