# How to use playwright expect to do an exact match of one of two possible values?

Tags: playwright

How can I use playwright `expect` to check for one of two exact matches?

Here's my function.

```
export const assertThirdPartyInternetPath = async (
  page: Page,
  path: string,
) => {
  expect(page.url()).toBe(path);
};
```

I am using it to test links to wikipedia pages.

`await this.assertThirdPartyInternetPath('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger'`

However, some sites like Wikipedia will redirect mobile devices (including playwright devices) to the `m` subdomain.

So I want to assert that the user is at either `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger` or `https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger`.  How can I do that?

Note that I want to do an exact match; I know I can use `expect(string.toContain(myPattern)` but I have various things to match and I want to do exact matches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reversing the comparison as suggested in [Jest matcher to match any one of three values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51519221/6243352) is possible, but makes the assertion message and overall flow a bit awkward.

```js
expect([
  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger",
  "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger",
]).toContain(page.url());
```

I'd prefer to use regex because it keeps the assertion in the normal direction:

```js
expect(page.url())
  .toMatch(/^https:\/\/en\.(?:m\.)?wikipedia\.org\/wiki\/Larry_Sanger$/);
```

The problems are readability and remembering to escape regex characters and add anchors. You could use a normal string and [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) with a bit of extra utility code.

Another option is to write a [custom matcher](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend):

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

expect.extend({
  async toBeAnyOf(received, ...possibilities) {
    if (possibilities.includes(received)) {
      return {
        message: () => "passed",
        pass: true,
      };
    }

    return {
      message: () =>
        `failed: '${received}' was not any of ${possibilities}`,
      pass: false,
    };
  },
});

test("is on the normal site", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger");
  expect(page.url()).toBeAnyOf(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger",
    "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger",
  );
});

test("is on the mobile site", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger");
  expect(page.url()).toBeAnyOf(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger",
    "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger",
  );
});
```

If you need auto-waiting, the regex will work in `toHaveURL`:

```js
await expect(page).toHaveURL(
  /^https:\/\/en\.(?:m\.)?wikipedia\.org\/wiki\/Larry_Sanger$/
);
```

`Promise.race()` is also possible. This avoids the regex and is pretty clear to read, but with the downside of being a bit verbose:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

test("navigate to one of two URLs", async ({page}) => {
  const url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger";
  const mobile = "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Sanger";
  await page.goto(Math.random() >= 0.5 ? url : mobile);
  await Promise.race([
    expect(page).toHaveURL(url),
    expect(page).toHaveURL(mobile),
  ]);
});
```