# Handling conditions with Playwright assertions

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, playwright

So the idea is that if the condition is False, then take some Action,
but for some reason, it make action with condition = false.
Appreciate any help!

```
  const condition = await expect(this.page.locator('#id')).toContainText('text');
  if (condition === false){
    await this.sendBtn.click();
    await expect(
      this.page.locator('#id'),
    ).toContainText('Done');
  } else {
    await expect(this.page.locator('#id')).toContainText('text');
  }
```

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Why do you want to do this? Conditions are not good to have in tests. If you are trying to test if an element has one of two text contents, see [How to use playwright expect to do an exact match of one of two possible values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75570005/how-to-use-playwright-expect-to-do-an-exact-match-of-one-of-two-possible-values/75570729#75570729).

Comment: Generally conditions are avoided in tests  however sometimes depending on scenario workflow its not possible to totally avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use playwright expect to do an exact match of one of two possible values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75570005/how-to-use-playwright-expect-to-do-an-exact-match-of-one-of-two-possible-values)

Answer (score 1):

In general , I agree that you should avoid adding conditions in tests
However I also know there are specific situations in long workflow where it cannot be avoided.

> Remember an **element may or may not exist on which you are performing
> an assertion** hence it may not necessarily return just 'true' or
> 'false' values.

That brings me to an important topic in JavaScript that the two statements(as below) are not exactly the same, although they can often be used interchangeably depending on the context.

#### if (condition === false)

This explicitly checks if the condition is equal to false. It evaluates to true if the condition is explicitly is `false` , not `falsy`.

#### if (!condition)

This checks if the condition is `falsy`. It evaluates to true if the condition is false, undefined, null, 0, an empty string, or NaN. It evaluates to false if the condition is truthy.

**Conclusion**: In many cases, especially when dealing with boolean values, these two statements are functionally equivalent. However, the first statement is more explicit in checking for false, while the second statement checks for falsiness, which includes various values.

**Suggestion**: So my suggestion is , to be mindful of this JS behaviour and use it wisely in your tests depending on the scenarios.

Comment: I totally agree that condition is a not good in tests, but in this particular case if we want tests to Pass it needs here,

Comment: I agree partially , please read my comment in the question. Also the intention should not just be to pass the tests but in fact reflect the true state of the AUT.

Comment: Ok I found the reason why it won't work, the reason is not in condition or truly false, the reason is that I was trying to assert that certain Id have certain text === false, so I changed a bit condition and it works. Thanks for your help!