# How can I expect two things when I don't know which will happen first?

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to write a Playwright test that does something after a form is submitted.  After that form is submitted, two things happen:

1. a "drawer" closes
2. a "notification" pops up

The problem is, the order of those two things can change, just due to randomness.  So whether I do:

```
await expectDrawerToClose();
await expectNotification();
```

or:

```
await expectNotification();
await expectDrawerToClose();
```

... either way it's going to be wrong sometimes.  Is there any way in Playwright to somehow do:

```
await expectTwoThingsToHappenInAnyOrder(
    expectDrawerToClose(),
    expectNotification()
);
```

I know that I can chain locators together with `or`, but that isn't the same thing: I don't want to say "I'll see one of these two things happen" ... I want to say "I'll see both happen; I just don't care about the order."

Comment: `await Promise.race([firstThing, secondThing])` that?

Comment: Yes, essentially ... just with Playwright stuff (expectations or locators) instead of promises.

Comment: My concern is, if I do `await Promise.race([expectNotification(), expectDrawerToClose()])` will Playwright's normal "I'll keep trying until I see things pass" logic still work?  I'd be afraid that the moment either expectation fails, the entire promise would fail, and Playwright wouldn't retry it.

Comment: Well, testing it out it *seems* like it works (although it's hard to tell with an inconsistent test like this).  If you'd like to put your comment into answer form, I'd happily accept it.

Comment: It's generally not necessary to write code like the proposed `expectTwoThingsToHappenInAnyOrder` pattern, even if it may seem like you do. I don't see a problem with sequential assertions when two things happen out of order. The first assertion passes regardless of the order, then the second passes. Why isn't that working out of the box? Can you share a [mcve]? The only reason for using some other approach is if the first condition totally blocks the second, and you don't know which will be first, but that's usually not the case. Is the "notification" a page-blocking alert? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, if I do `await expectDrawerToClose()` playwright waits until the drawer closes.  If the notification appears, and then goes away, during that time, then when I do `await expectNotification()` after, the test fails.

Comment: Although, I *could* write `expectDrawerToBeClosed()` instead, and it should work as long as I call it after `expectNotification()` ... still, I'm sure this pattern is necessary sometimes, so I'm curious to learn the correct way to handle it when it is needed.

Comment: A [mcve] is still helpful so we have an agreed-upon goal, without me having to guess. The fact that the notification dismisses after a moment wasn't apparent.

Comment: @Michael `Promise.race()` doesn't seem right, since it may only assert the first predicate. `Promise.all()` will wait for both to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need, most of the time. The sequential assertions just work, as long as the behavior isn't performing a complete block on the page (as would be the case with an `alert()`, which prevents rendering) or if one state may disappear while Playwright is still waiting for the other condition.

Consider the following example:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button>click me</button>
<div class="drawer closed">closed</div>
<script>
const openDrawer = () => {
  const drawer = document.querySelector(".drawer");
  drawer.classList.remove("closed");
  drawer.classList.add("open");
  drawer.textContent = "open";
};

const showNotification = () => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.textContent = "notification!";
  document.body.append(el);
};

document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", e => {
    setTimeout(openDrawer, Math.random() * 2000);
    setTimeout(showNotification, Math.random() * 2000);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

test("button triggers drawer and notification", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByRole("button", {name: "click me"}).click();
  await expect(page.getByText("notification!")).toBeVisible();
  await expect(page.locator(".open")).toBeVisible();
});
```

Although the two events happen in arbitrary order in the 2 seconds following the click, this test is guaranteed to pass. The order of the assertions doesn't matter.

Based on [one of your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77623647/how-can-i-expect-two-things-when-i-dont-know-which-will-happen-first/77623783#comment136846952_77623647), you note that the notification may be dismissed after a short duration. In that case, order matters. Assert the temporary state before the longer/permanent state:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button>click me</button>
<div class="drawer closed">closed</div>
<script>
const openDrawer = () => {
  const drawer = document.querySelector(".drawer");
  drawer.classList.remove("closed");
  drawer.classList.add("open");
  drawer.textContent = "open";
};

const showNotification = () => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.textContent = "notification!";
  document.body.append(el);
  setTimeout(() => el.remove(), 1000);
};

document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", e => {
    setTimeout(openDrawer, Math.random() * 2000);
    setTimeout(showNotification, Math.random() * 2000);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

test("button triggers drawer and notification", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByRole("button", {name: "click me"}).click();

  // assert temporary state first
  await expect(page.getByText("notification!")).toBeVisible();
  await expect(page.locator(".open")).toBeVisible();
});
```

If *both* states disappear nondeterministically, and need to be asserted truly concurrently, then you can use `Promise.all`:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button>click me</button>
<div class="drawer closed">closed</div>
<script>
const openDrawer = () => {
  const drawer = document.querySelector(".drawer");
  drawer.classList.remove("closed");
  drawer.classList.add("open");
  drawer.textContent = "open";
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      el.classList.remove("open");
      el.textContent = "closed";
    },
    Math.random() * 1000 + 500
  );
};

const showNotification = () => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.textContent = "notification!";
  document.body.append(el);
  setTimeout(
    () => el.remove(),
    Math.random() * 1000 + 500
  );
};

document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", e => {
    setTimeout(openDrawer, Math.random() * 2000);
    setTimeout(showNotification, Math.random() * 2000);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

test("button triggers drawer and notification", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByRole("button", {name: "click me"}).click();
  await Promise.all([
    expect(page.getByText("notification!")).toBeVisible(),
    expect(page.locator(".open")).toBeVisible(),
  ]);
});
```

If you find you're using the `Promise.all()` pattern often in your tests, then either you have an unusually dynamic and remarkable website, or you're overusing it (probably the latter). Prefer properly-ordered straight-line assertions like snippet 2 above, unless there's truly no other option.

If you want to take the first of multiple states and ignore the rest, use `Promise.race` instead of `Promise.all`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75570729/6243352) for an example. Use judiciously.

if you're not using `@playwright/test`, you can remove the `expect`s and use `.waitFor()` instead of `.toBeVisible()`.