# How can I debug a "ghost" row element in Playwright?

Tags: playwright

I have a basic Playwright locator:

```
page.locator('.some-table tbody tr');
```

I'm trying to use it to test a paginated table with 100 rows per page.  When I run my test:

```
 const rows = page.locator('.some-table tbody tr');
 expect(await rows.count(), '# of rows').toEqual(100);
```

the first page passes, as expected.

However, when I run an identical test, after clicking a button to go to page #2, it fails, because it sees a 101 total rows.

Now, I've confirmed in my browser (with `$$('.some-table tbody tr').length`) that both pages have exactly 100 rows.  Also, I can iterate through all the rows, and their content lines up with what I see on the page ...

... except on page #2.  When I loop through all the rows on page #2:

```
const rows = await page.locator('.some-table tbody tr').all();
for (const row of rows) {
    console.log('\n', await row.textContent(), i);
}
```

the test times out when it tries to get the `textContent` of the "ghost" 101st row.  All 100 rows before log their contents just fine, but row #101 times out.

If I try logging the `innerHtml` instead, the same thing happens:

> Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.

> Error: locator.innerHTML: Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.

In summary, Playwright is finding a 101st row on page #2, but not on page #1 (even though both have 100 rows only).  I have no idea where this "ghost" row is coming from, and I can't even figure anything out about it, because it times out whenever I try to see its details.

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Please share the site and your code as a [mcve].

Comment: I have.  The only part I didn't include was the test wrapper, as its irrelevant.  Well, that and 100 rows of the page's HTML, which won't help anyone.

Comment: I can't run what's posted--there's no site, so it's not reproducible. Generally, `expect(await rows.count(), '# of rows').toEqual(100);` should be `await expect(rows).toHaveCount(100)`, using a web first assertion. I've never heard of "ghost" elements. Either Playwright sees an element, or it doesn't (at least as far as text contents are concerned, some actions require visibility as well). There must be some sensible explanation for it, but it's hard to guess that without seeing the page.

Comment: Of course it should.  But it's not: that's my whole problem.  The really interesting part isn't that a locator is coming back with 101 results on a page with 100 rows though (which you could attribute to user error); it's that the 101st row times out when I try and look at it.  If I could just see its HTML I could understand why Playwright sees 101 rows ... but I can't.  So I'm asking: does anyone know how to debug an element that times out on `innerHtml()` ... or can they explain what type of element would do that.

Comment: Your second code snippet, `const rows = await page.locator('.some-table tbody tr').all();` is not recommended, because the elements can be removed from the document between the creation of the `rows` handles array and when you try to extract each element's text, and it requires 101 network calls rather than one. The standard approach is `await page.locator(".some-table tr").allTextContents()`.

Comment: Will try using `allTextContents` and report back

Comment: Please note your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77623783/6243352). The answer uses minimal, complete, runnable snippets to unambiguously communicate the scenarios, problems and solutions, so I suggest doing the same for questions such as this one. If the page has complex behavior you can't create a repro of, share the actual page if you can. If you can't, which is sometimes the case due to passwords and keeping information private, the best I can do is guess.

Comment: Guesses are good: they are more than I have!  `allTextContents` didn't work on the ghost row (it timed out like `innerHTML`), but then I tried using it on the whole table.  I got back so much text I had to split it up and log the pieces .... and then I switched to `innerHTML` to get the HTML ... and then I was finally able to see what Playwright is seeing.  I need to dig in to it to figure out if it's user error or a true bug, but you've answered my question.  Care to put something like "use innerHTML on the parent element, and chunk up the console.logs if there's a lot" into a formal answer?

Comment: (I know you didn't suggest `innerHTML`, but you suggested using `allTextContents` which was basically the same thing, and it gave me the idea.  You certainly deserve the credit for the answer.)

Comment: That's good. Generally, drill all the way down to leaf elements (probably `<td>`s) before extracting text. I'll pass on an answer until I actually know what's going on, but you can always [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you think it has value.

Comment: I can do that, but just wanted you to get the points.  Sadly, there will be no final answer: after wasting too much time trying to debug this bug, I opted to instead add a `await page.waitForTimeout(1000);` which fixed the problem.  It doesn't explain or solve the "ghost row", it just avoids it ... but that's going to have to be good enough, as I don't have endless hours to research ghost rows :(

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really about points, it's about solving problems, which I can't do without the problem. [`page.waitForTimeout(1000)` is a poor solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352). It's better to figure out the actual predicate, so there's no slowness or flakiness. Glad you have a workaround though, but if you were to share the problem reproducibly, we could get an actual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @ggorlen I realized that I could inspect the "ghost row" by inspecting its parent instead.  In other words, instead of doing the following (in a loop):

```
console.log('\n', await row.textContent(), i);
```

I did this (without looping):

```
console.log('\n', await page.locator('.some-table tbody').innerHtml());
```

This at least let me log the `tbody`'s HTML, so I could see my "ghost row" ... although there was so much HTML in that log that it actually got truncated, and I had to split the (very long) string into several smaller strings in order to actually see them in the logs.

Sadly, doing all that didn't give me any further insight into why Playwright was finding a ghost row ... but I did discover that by adding an extra second of wait, I could eliminate the ghost.

So, unfortunately there's no satisfying answer as to the mystery of the ghost row itself, but at least (again, thanks to @ggorlen) I was able to figure out how to "inspect" that row.